# Passing variables from batch script subroutine to subroutine

Tags: variables, batch-file, set, call, subroutine

I have batch1 (the parent batch) which calls batch2, 3, etc.  Batch2 does some stuff, sets a variable (%fullname%) and exits.  Batch 3 is supposed to use the variable from batch2.

Batch1

```
Call Batch2
echo %fullname%
Call Batch3
```

I've tried

```
Call Batch 3 %fullname%
Call Batch3 %1
etc
```

The echo %fullname% is successful in Batch1.  The %fullname% is not getting into Batch3.  I hope this is something simple that I'm missing because I'm tired of looking at this batch file.  Plus, I have a lot of variables and calls, more than this example shows.

Should I ditch the parent batch and have the child batches call each other?  Simpler? e.g.  Batch1 calls Batch2, batch2 calls batch3, batch3 calls batch4 etc.

I've googled this.  The question is apparently too simple to have been asked before.

Comment: Is the content of `%fullname%` successfully echoed in batch1? Do you use setlocal`s in your batch files?

Comment: The echo %fullname% is successful in Batch1.

Comment: There are no `setlocal`s in batch 2 or 3.  I use a `setlocal` in batch1, but it is after this example i provided.

Comment: What is the content of `fullname`? Something special with spaces or characters like `"<>&|%!`? What you see in batch3 when you add `echo %*` at the beginning?

Comment: `%fullname%` is firstname lastname.  All text with a space.  I have the problem with variables that are numbers as well.

Comment: tell me more about your variables problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the fullname/displayname example was a bad example.  Found the error while I copy and pasting the code into this thread.  Batch2 set "displayname".  Batch3 called "dname".  Forgot to change the variable name to match.  Still having a problem w/ passing other parameters to other batches.  Will start a different thread with the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

batchone.bat:

```
@echo off
call batchtwo.bat
call batchthree.bat
pause
exit
```

save as batchone.bat

batchtwo.bat:

```
@echo off
::insert code here
set fullname=mechengr02
exit /b
```

save as batchtwo.bat

batchthree.bat:

```
@echo off
echo hello %fullname%
exit /b
```

save as batchthree.bat

note that these are three different batch files. i just tested it.

[image: proof]
hope that helped!

Comment: Yes it works.  Found the error while I copy and pasting the code into this thread.  Batch2 set "displayname".  Batch3 called "dname".  Forgot to change the variable name to match.